# .NET XMPP libraries for Xamarin

Tags: library, c#, .net, xmpp

I need to write a mobile chat client using XMPP and Xamarin but I can’t seem to find a decent XMPP library anywhere.

- Jabber-net is too old and references Windows.Forms
- agsXMPP references System.Drawing (so it can’t compile for Android)
- Matrix is way too expensive

Has anyone managed to come across a decent solution?